# JIRA Python use a string to access class

Tags: python, jira-rest-java-api

I need help with getting the following function working.

The issue I can't solve how to reference the function with a string.

- This line works

  ```
  field_value = results.fields.customfield_10000
  ```
- This line does not, as the string value of custom_field is customfield_10000

  ```
  field_value = results.fields.custom_field
  ```

This is the full function

```
def get_customfield_value(results, custom_field):
    field_value = results.fields.custom_field
    return field_value

from jira.client import JIRA
jira_options={'server': 'http://localhost:8080'}
jira=JIRA(options=jira_options,basic_auth=('usrname','pwd'))

results = jira.search_issues(' some jql retuning issues ')
fieldValue = get_customfield_value(results, "customfield_10000")
```

I've looked at `locals()` and `globals()` but not sure if this is the right thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`__getattribute__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__).

```
from jira import JIRA

jira = JIRA('https://jira.atlassian.com')
issue = jira.issue('JRA-9')
issue.fields.__getattribute__(issue.fields,'customfield_11437')
```

So in your case, this should work:

```
def get_customfield_value(results, custom_field):
    field_value = results.fields.__getattribute__(results.fields,custom_field)
    return field_value
```